# UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable methods for UISlider not responding

Tags: ios, uislider, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to figure out how to set the accessibility `Increment`/ `Decrement` of an `UISlider` with stepping. It keeps saying that the value is 0%, which it shouldn't. I also wonder if this is the reason why the `accessibilityValue` is not working..

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class RateAppViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingSlider: UISlider!

    let steps: Float = 0.2

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // UpdateUI
        updateUI()

        // InitalizeAccessibility
        initalizeAccessibility()
    }

    private func updateUI() {

        ratingSlider.value = 0.2
        ratingSlider.minimumValue = 0.2
        ratingSlider.maximumValue = 1.0
    }

    private func initalizeAccessibility() {

        ratingSlider.isAccessibilityElement = true
        ratingSlider.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable
        ratingSlider.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("Rating", comment: "RatingView Label")
        ratingSlider.accessibilityIncrement()
        ratingSlider.accessibilityDecrement()
    }

    override func accessibilityIncrement() {
        ratingSlider.value += steps
        setRating(ratingSlider.value)
    }

    override func accessibilityDecrement() {
        ratingSlider.value -= steps
        setRating(ratingSlider.value)
    }

    private func setRating(value: Float) {

        let stars: Int = Int(value * 5)
        print(stars)

        if value == 0.2 {
            ratingSlider.accessibilityValue = NSLocalizedString("1 star", comment: "One Star RatingSlider")
        } else {
            ratingSlider.accessibilityValue = NSLocalizedString("\(stars) Stars", comment: "Multiple Stars RatingSlider")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func ratingValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        let roundSteps = round(sender.value / steps) * steps
        sender.value = roundSteps
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to subclass UISlider and implement the methods in that class.